# How to take parameter values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to write a JavaScript function that takes the parameters and assigns parameter value to a variable...how to do this...

here is what i have tried.....

```
function getTextWidth(text, fontname, fontsize) () {
     var one = text;
     var two = fontname;
     var three = fontsize;
    });
```

is this correct?

Comment: NO need ); after your function body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getTextWidth(text, fontname, fontsize) {
     var one = text;
     var two = fontname;
     var three = fontsize;
    }
```

You need to remove the extra brackets at the end of your function before the first opening `{`.  Then you need to remove the trailing bracket and semi-colon.  It looks like you are mixing a JavaScript function with jQuery.

Comment: It should be noted that these variables will only live within the function, so the function effectively does nothing.

Comment: true,removing my useless comment :D

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect syntax. See this for an example of how to declare a function with parameters:

```
function getTextWidth(text, fontname, fontsize) {
     var one = text;
     var two = fontname;
     var three = fontsize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `()` just before the `{` in your function, and replace the `});` with `};`

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is -

```
function getTextWidth(text, fontname, fontsize){
     var one = text;
     var two = fontname;
     var three = fontsize;
}
```

- http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_functions

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for var one = text; etc - "text" is already a variable available to your function

Answer (score 0):

no need for extra ()

```
function getTextWidth(text, fontname, fontsize) {
         var one = text || false,
            two = fontname || false,
            three = fontsize || false;

        if (one) {

        }

        if (two) {

        }

        if (three) {

        }
    });
```

and then you can call `getTextWidth('foobar', 'arial', '12px);`